# How should one go about deciphering "ZPLKKWL MFUPP UFL XA EUXMFLP"?

Tags: puzzle, cryptography

The Princeton companion to mathematics says, "it is just possible to work out the meaning of the above example by matching letter patterns to those commonly seen in English, but it is quite challenging!" but they leave out the solution.

Comment: This questions looks better suited for puzzling.se. On the other hand, I'd try matching the 3 and 2 letter words with the most common words with that number of characters.

Comment: Notice the KK? The most common double letter in English is LL. Try that. If that doesn't work, try SS or TT.

Comment: For instance, E is a very, very common vowel and shows up as the second to last or last letter in a lot of words.  In your above phrase, $L\to E$ is a very good candidate as it's the last letter in 2 of them (Including the 3 letter word that is very likely "THE"),  and the second to last in another.

Answer (score 3):

Using [this](http://rumkin.com/tools/cipher/cryptogram-solver.php) cryptogram solver, I get the solution "Freddie Starr ate my hamster".